# How do WP child-themes work?

Tags: child-theme

Ok, I have my main theme setup, and now I created a child theme with the name interio_child.

From these [instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) I understand that you only need to add the style.css file which makes the link to your main theme.

Also you can add additional files which override code from your main theme.

Right now I have activated my child theme. It only displays the code that is present in my child theme folder and no CSS at all. How is this possible?

I've looked at numerous tutorials and wordpress support topics, but I can't get this child theme linked to my main theme.

These are the contents from my child theme's style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Interio Child
Theme URI: http://tohidgolkar.com
Author: Tohid Golkar
Author URI: http://tohidgolkar.com
Description: Child theme for the Interio theme 
Template: interio
Version: 1.1
*/

@import url('../interio/style.css');
@import url('stylesheets/mystyle.css');
```

Does the child theme folder need to contain all files from the main theme? I believe not, it should link with the main theme, correct? Then why are there no files from the main theme displayed on the website?

Comment: Here's useful tutorial for child themes [child-themes](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/child-themes-basics-and-creating-child-themes-in-wordpress/). Regards.

Comment: What does *not displayed* mean in your question? As far as CSS files are concerned, you can find out by looking into the network tab inside the developer console of your browser. It shows you 404 errors and such. Also your webserver does. So what have you done so far to actually find out what could cause your issue? From your question so far I read that you're new to child themes, however that must not mean that child themes itself cause the problem here. It can be a simple CSS issue, better troubleshoot then wonder :)

Comment: Ok hakre, My import worked right after I deleted my header.php, footer.php and functions.php from the child theme folder. From what I understand you can create new (incomplete) versions of these files, which only contains the changes you want to make to the theme. Is this correct? If so, why does my theme stop functioning when I upload these files?

Comment: I don't think that you can replace *any* file in a childtheme but only some. I would double check if functions.php always works or if this needs some special handling. But just seeing it should work out of the box. If you see nothing, you likely have a white page of death probably. Do you get a 500 (internal server error) status code with your blank page? If so, log PHP errors to file (you can configure that in php.ini) and follow the error log. It should tell you where you made a mistake).

Comment: @hakre I found why it wouldn't work. There's a special rule for the functions.php which is reloaded in addition to the main theme functions.php. The OTHER php files I need to copy entirely, and then make adjustments to them :) Very sad that this was not documented in the wordpress.com child theme tutorial. I found this information [here](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-child-theme)

Comment: The `functions.php` file in child themes usually have local references and links to other files within the template folder itself. If you copy the `funtions.php` file rather then adding content you will get errors. [Unlike style.css, the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s file.)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) Therefore you should only add aditional functions rather then copying the file itself.

Comment: Just saw your comment and the info you mention is documented in the [Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) codex entry under Using functions.php

Comment: What @FernandoSilva wrote, that's straight forward documented in the Codex page. I also looked that up, it was not clear to me you really copied the file verbatim. In any case, it's documented, sometimes it's just being patient enough to read (and udnerstand). It is important you do proper error handling and provide those if you get a blank page. Remember that for future problems you run into. Most of them you can fix yourself if you know where to look ;)

Comment: @hakre; I did noticed the exception for functions.php :) However, i misread for other php files. I thought all files where loaded in addition to their counterpart, but that was not true. I had an incomplete header file so my stylesheets where never loaded, and thus no CSS was applied. The document i mentioned (which on itself is mentioned in the bottom of wordpress child themes page) stated this specifically. That is how I solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

From your css snippet it looks like you child theme's styles are located in the /stylesheets/mystyle.css file. Make sure that the file is actually being imported.

I'd suggest either placing your css within the style.css file rather than a second import. But if you require the second file then modify your @import to `@import url('/stylesheets/mystyle.css');`.

Comment: Import works now :) But only for one file. The other stylesheet I have imported exactly the same way, but this one does not work. The style inside it must overrule a style in the original template. But that doesn't happen... Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: Is the site publicly available? Can you share a URL?

Comment: Just for clarification, is `mystyle.css` in your child theme folder and supposed to be you child theme's CSS file? If so you should call it `style.css` and remove `@import url('/stylesheets/mystyle.css');` as it will be used automatically.

Comment: Still recovering from errors and long before finished, but i've uploaded the site right [here](http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey)

Comment: @FernandoSilva, no. The main css file for the child theme is style.css in the child theme's root folder. The parent theme contains 8 css files in a /stylesheets/ folder. I need to edit several of them for the child theme, and for that WP demands the same folder structure as for the parent theme. Mystyle.css is a newly created stylesheet, but shortcodes.css already exists in the main theme. I've created a new shortcodes.css in the childtheme with an addition to it, but that doesn't work.

Comment: So the files are being imported, it may be a question of CSS overrides.

Comment: @Stephen yes, the ovveride does not work in this case.

Comment: @Stephen, For clarification, check out [this .panel class](http://rickgommers.nl/geoffrey/wp-content/themes/interio_child/stylesheets/shortcodes.css). This is the stylesheet that doesn't work right now

Comment: @Stephen where you able to find onsite why this class isn't loaded?

Comment: that is because the parent theme loads the stylesheets after style.css of the child theme - lok into the code of hte head section in your browser. any stylesheet you load with @import in your child theme will be called before those of the parent theme. consider to enqueue the child theme's stylesheets http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: This looks interesting. My theme has already an enqueue.php file which I can edit for this matter. Thx for mentioning this @Michael!

Comment: @Forza If it did the trick for you let Michael know so he can put it into an answer so it can be accepted^^

Comment: @Michael donno if you can stil post an answer now the question is closed, but your answer would be marked as accepted :)